# How does "Startup Applications" work?

Tags: 14.04, autostart

I am interested in knowing how "Startup Applications", which you can access from the dock, work.

I want to know this because I want to know the difference between adding an entry in these places:

```
/etc/rc.local 
/etc/profile  
/home/$USER/.profile
```

and doing the same via this GUI application. What puzzles me is that I don't see the program creating any entries in the above mentioned files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `/etc/rc.local`

  ```
  # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
  # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
  # value on error.
  ```

  Essentially the Multiuser Runlevel means when you boot up.
- `/etc/profile`

  This file is invoked only for login shells because that is its specific purpose.

  `/etc/profile`, run by all Bourne-compatible shells (including `bash` and `dash`) when started as a login shell.
- `/home/$USER/.profile`

  ```
  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
  # This file is not read by bash if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
  # exists.
  ```

  > Both the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` are scripts that may be executed when bash is invoked. The `~/.bashrc` file gets executed when you run bash using an interactive shell that is not a login shell. The `~/.bash_profile` only gets executed during a login shell.

  <sup>[**Source**](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile)</sup>

  So I think `.profile` gets executed if neither of those were (for whatever reason).
- Finally, your GUI method is *probably* putting `.desktop` launchers in `/home/$USER/.config/autostart`

  This is run at user logon (GUI login only I think - so `startx` would but not `tty` login).

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Won't .profile commands get executed at GUI login?

Comment: @user3073656 hmmm what's the GUI application called?

Comment: Sorry, careless mistake! You were right.

Comment: @user3073656 edited

Answer (score 8):

Any desktop environment following the [freedesktop specifications](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/) (aka XDG) should make use of [autostarting applications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) on user login or whenever a removable medium was inserted.

For autostarting an application at user login the desktop environment looks for a `.desktop` file to execute the application specified there. This `.desktop` files usually are located in

```
$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/autostart
```

But we can also have them in the following locations:

```
~/.config/autostart/ ## if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set
etc/xdg/autostart/ ## if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is not set
```

In any case a `.desktop` file located in `~/.config/autostart` is defined as being the most important file to be run thus overriding `.desktop` files in other locations.

Ubuntu fulfills this specification and users can add applications with a GUI approach to "Autostart Applications".

Application can be auto-started independent of the desktop from various other locations such as `~/.profile` for the shell, in `/etc/rc.local` for running at system start or, more recently by using [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).

Comment: Adding the commands this way is best as this literally doesn't take time when compared to the .profile file where we add our startup commands. I have tested both of these on my dell inspiron 7560 with ubuntu 16.04 and this way seems better.

Comment: I also guess this is better than editing the /etc/profile file as it is invoked only for login shells that is after the desktop environment gets started. Yup, tested that as well. I was right.